# Are there other options for updating widgets than SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Android 14 apps that targets android 13 and higher started require permission for SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM. Are there other ways to update widget (every 1 second) without the need to ask for permission? Or do I neeed to use it?

USE_EXACT_ALARM cant be used